# Get GetItemCheckState (in Form2) of checkedCheckList (Form1)

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, select, textbox

I'm current creating a kind of menu where users should select several mods of a checkedCheckList and then in a second form they should provide the mod-profile-path in a textbox. If a mod is not selected the textbox should be disabled. How do I disable a textbox if an item of checkedCheckList is not selected?

Here's the code:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
public void checkCheckedState()
{
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0) == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        form2.textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Forms2's textBox1 Modifiers is set to public.

And here are some screenshots:
[image]

After hitting the button the menu where to enter the details:
[image]

How do I disable the TextBox if a specific item of the checkedCheckBox of Form1 is not selected?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There should be a CheckedChanged event for the `checkedCheckBox`. Run `checkCheckedState()` within that event.

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately not working. The textbox remains active.

Comment: Oh I'm so very sorry, I have the answer for you. See my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Multiple Form GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636598/creating-multiple-form-gui)

Comment: So I do best by saving the values in a repo and not accessing it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stackoverflow.com/a/19259986/2367343](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19259986/2367343)

WPF (Same idea as WinForms) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041212/2367343

This answer shows you how to pass one form to another. I use this way when I need to change anything on the calling form from another form it opened up.