# Update between two Windows in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following Code:

Window 1:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondWindow sndW = new SecondWindow(btnFirstWindow);
        sndW.Show();
    }


<Grid>
    <Button Name="btnFirstWindow" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Height="70" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Second Window:

```
        private Button firstWindowButton;
    public SecondWindow(Button firstWindowButton) {
        this.firstWindowButton = firstWindowButton;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        firstWindowButton.Click += firstWindowButton_Click;
    }
    void firstWindowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblShowUser.Content = "First window button clicked on: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

<Label Name="lblShowUser" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="92" Width="205"/>
```

It should change the content from lblShowUser in window2, if I press the button from window1. Got this example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040681/how-to-update-list-on-one-window-when-some-event-trigger-on-another-window-in-wp). But it won't work..
The two windows will open, but the content won't change. If i set the content from the label to "test", it won't change to the correct time like "First window button clicked on: ..."

Comment: `But it won't work.` Please tell us what won't work. Also, if there is an exception, please add the exception.

Comment: okey, i added a little description. Hopefully its helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this code
     firstWindowButton.Click += firstWindowButton_Click;

to SecondWindow constructor. So it should look like this:

```
    public SecondWindow(Button firstWindowButton) {
    this.firstWindowButton = firstWindowButton;
    firstWindowButton.Click += firstWindowButton_Click;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! But it only works, if a new window will open everytime i press the button ?

Comment: If you want you can add one more button, so one button will open new window and another button will change label text

Comment: Well.. everytime i ask things it's so simple.. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to bind the two windows to the same `ViewModel`, and define that ViewModel as s `StaticResource` in the *App.xaml*:

Add a `Command` class and a `SharedViewModel` class and define the needed Properties/Commands:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    public Command(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
public class SharedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _labelText;
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return _labelText; }
        set
        {
            _labelText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private ICommand _buttonClickCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonClickCommand => _buttonClickCommand ?? (_buttonClickCommand = new Command(ButtonClickAction));

    public void ButtonClickAction()
    {
        LabelText = "Updated Text";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Define the `SharedViewModel` instance as `StaticResource` in *App.xaml*:

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<local:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModel"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window1:

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{StaticResource SharedViewModel}">

<Grid>
    <Button Name="BtnFirstWindow" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Height="70"  Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Window2

```
Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{StaticResource SharedViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Label Name="lblShowUser" Content="{Binding LabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="92" Width="205"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wow, that will help me a lot in a few days.. At the moment i don't know that much about MVVM. But it will be the next step, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the DataContext of these two windows to one common ViewModel. then set the Datacontext of the new Window to the old one.
like -

```
Window2 Obj = new();
obj.DataContext = this;
obj.Show();
```

do like in your first Window then all updates / changes will occur accordingly.